# How to Show multiple record from table mysql to telegram bot with python , and only certain phone number can access to my bot telegram

Tags: python, mysql, python-telegram-bot

im still beginner with python script. I want to ask like the title name,
i got idea innovation for monitoring KPI on my office, and almost done. but there are problem can't finished by myself.

How to Show multiple record from table mysql to telegram bot with python , and only certain phone number can access to my bot telegram ?

This my script :

**'How to show multiple record from table mysql to telegram bot'**

```
def query(requ):
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM monitor WHERE Tanggal LIKE '%" + str(requ.encode('utf-8')) + "%'"

try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    # memecahkan hasil dari table
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    # memberikan hasil jika hasil sesuai sama tabel maka keluar sesuai hasil
    if len(results)>0:
        output = ''
        for row in results:
            Tanggal = row[0]
            DOWNTIME_PLN = row[1]
            RUN_GENSET = row[2]
            SHREDDER_MILL_DOWNTIME = row[3]
            SHREDDER_CRUMB_DOWNTIME = row[4]
            SHREDDER_CRUMB_AMPERE = row[5]
            has_trans = row[6]
            # Now print fetched result
            output = "Tanggal = %s, \nDOWNTIME_PLN = %d, \nRUN_GENSET = %s, \nSHREDDER_MILL_DOWNTIME = %s, \nSHREDDER_CRUMB_DOWNTIME=%s, \nSHREDDER_CRUMB_AMPERE=%s, \nhas_trans = %s" % \
            (Tanggal,DOWNTIME_PLN,RUN_GENSET,SHREDDER_MILL_DOWNTIME,SHREDDER_CRUMB_DOWNTIME,SHREDDER_CRUMB_AMPERE,has_trans)
            print (Tanggal,DOWNTIME_PLN,RUN_GENSET,SHREDDER_MILL_DOWNTIME,SHREDDER_CRUMB_DOWNTIME,SHREDDER_CRUMB_AMPERE,has_trans)
    else:
        output = 'No word in my dic'
except:
    output = 'error'
return output
```

'How to only certain phone number can access to my bot telegram ?'

```
def handle(msg):
#Deklarasi untuk profile Telegram
chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
command = msg['text']
user_id = msg['from']['id']
username = msg['from']['first_name']
fullname = msg['from']['last_name']+msg['from']['first_name']
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H")

content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)

if (content_type == 'text'):
    command = msg['text']
    print ('Got command: %s' % command)
    #Dekklarasi command apa saja yang mau dimasukin
    if command == 'halo':
        keyboard = [
            ['Halo', 'erlang'],
            ['cpu', 'ddd'],
            ['ccc'],['Tutup']
        ]
        reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup.create(keyboard)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Assalamu'alaikum "+username+", ..?",reply_markup=reply_markup)
    elif command == 'erlang':
        bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open('E:/@@@/@smartfren/capture trial/Compare_KPI_1' + '.jpg','rb'))
        bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open('E:/@@@/@smartfren/capture trial/Compare_KPI_2' + '.jpg','rb'))
    elif command == 'cpu':
        print ('Got command: %s' % timestr + command)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, :test:)
    elif 'Tutup' in command:
        hide_keyboard = {'hide_keyboard': True}
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Fungsi KeyBoard ditutup!', reply_markup=hide_keyboard)
    elif 'ccc' in command:
        reps_content = query(command)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, reps_content)
    elif 'ddd' in command:
        reps_content = query2(command)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, reps_content)
```

Thanks :)